# MonetDB "server requires unknown hash"

Tags: monetdb

I built MonetDB from source. After I unpack the tarball, I followed these steps:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

I was able to install monetdbd and mclient, and they are both at version 11.39.7.
However, when I follow [the tutorial to create a new database](https://www.monetdb.org/index.php/Documentation/Tutorial/GettingStarted/CreateADatabase), mclient cannot authenticate even the default user (monetdb):

```
$> mclient -u monetdb -d imdb
password: (I entered 'monetdb')
server requires unknown hash 'SHA512'
```

What does this "server requires unknown hash 'SHA512'" mean? How can I resolve this?

p.s. I also tried to change the configuration so that it only uses MD5, but I then get a similar message: "server requires unknown hash 'MD5'".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the "openssl" library on your system. Which OS are you using?

You need the development packages: `openssl-devel` on RPM-based systems, `libssl-dev` on Debian like systems.  Look also in `debian/control` inside the tar ball to see what is required

FYI, since the Oct2020, MonetDB/e (i.e. MonetDB embedded) doesn't require openssl, so MonetDB has dropped this requirement.  However, when you use the MonetDB client-server, you need this library.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. However, I had openssl installed (via sudo apt-get install openssl) before I ran cmake and make. I can verify that by running `openssl help` and see a number of options (I see sha512, but not "SHA512"). Is there any other configurations I need to run before cmake and make? btw, I am using ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Hi, I just updated my previous answer.  See above.  Hope this helps.